# Advice to Non-Jew about Days of HaMoshiach

Tags: gentiles, ymoth-hamoshiach

A non Jew has recently asked me that if Moshiach is coming soon, what should he do?

It's a very vague question but it kind of has to be. We don't know what the coming of Moshiach looks like or if it is even soon. It might be delightful, it might be dangerous. It might be done, it might require more work. It might be difficult for those without a connection to Hashem and mitzvot, it might be that it will be great for such people as it will redeem them. So many similar questions.

If we should offer advice about how to do well in the lead up to and coming of the Moshiach to a non Jew, what would we advise?

Source based answers please. Did any Sefer, sugya or sicha deal with this, or can anyone think of anything relevant?

Obvious answers are:

- Learn about 7 mitzvot benei Noach and start keeping them
- Learn Torah (what's allowed anyway)
- Learn about Hashem, and His servant Moshe, and do the above because they said so.
- Do teshuva (what would that look like for a non Jew?)

What else? Any more specific advice or any points more subtle than the above?

Comment: Have them practice sitting in a Sukkah on their roof on a hot day and *not* kicking it as per Avodah Zarah 3b/4a?

Comment: @יהושעק The Torah says the non Jews will kick the Succah on their way out, but we are meant to leave in a sullen way, like a servant who just had the wine he brought to the king rejected and thrown in his face. The lesson here is we are doing the Mitzvah to please Him, not gain a benefit for ourselves. This therefore falls under learning Torah and getting to know Hashem

Comment: Relevant: https://tablet.otzar.org/#/book/631188/p/25/t/0.67072839704081931234/fs/8TboTdppTTs6aNDXyUTKvRz1vkkj2L8R6I6dVs2rg6gX/start/2100/end/2142/c (starting from והענין דע).

Comment: True, @Rabbi Kaii....but it's also something they can put into practice immediately even without the extra dose of spiritual awareness they will get when Mashiach comes (may it be very soon!)

Comment: @יהושעק I was just thinking that, good point. Amen

Comment: I think you covered it.

Answer (score 2):

The Talmud says that the Messiah will come when the Jews are in deep trouble:

> Rabbi Yoḥanan says: If you saw a generation whose wisdom and Torah study is steadily diminishing, await the coming of the Messiah, as it is stated: “And the afflicted people You will redeem” (II Samuel 22:28). Rabbi Yoḥanan says: If you saw a generation whose troubles inundate it like a river, await the coming of the Messiah, as it is stated: “When distress will come like a river that the breath of the Lord drives” (Isaiah 59:19). And juxtaposed to it is the verse: “And a redeemer will come to Zion” (Isaiah 59:20). [Sanhedrin 98a]

So non-Jews should help Jews in times of trouble to acquire favor with the Messiah.

Comment: Bit of a non sequitur. Sotah 49b says wine will be expensive before Moshiach comes. Does that imply non-Jews should prepare for Moshiach by driving down wine prices?